# Capture the type of error it is returning (500,503,402, etc) and add that in the message?

Tags: bash

How do I make this script to capture the type of error it is returning (500,503,402, etc) and add that in the message?

```
#!/bin/bash
hostlist=(s-colin.coverhound.us s-joe.coverhound.us)
  for host in "${hostlist[@]}"; do
if nc -w 2 -z $host 80; then
    echo "INFO: ssh on $host responding [Looks Good]"
else
    echo "ERROR: ssh on $host not responding[Ooops something went 
  wrong]"
fi
done
```

Comment: Are you really checking for ssh on port 80? Are you interested in HTTP response codes?

Answer (score 1):

Your current script does not perform an HTTP request, so there is no HTTP response and thus no HTTP result code to report. `nc -z` simply attempts to establish a TCP connection, then immediately quits and tells you whether that succeeded or not. A proper HTTP client would not do that; it would send a valid HTTP `GET` or `POST` request once the TCP connection is established, and wait for the server's response to it, then report that back to the user somehow.

You should probably add another action to your script to connect using e.g. `curl` if the `nc` test succeeds. What exactly to test for is mildly unclear, but a common thing to check is that fetching the start page works.

```
if curl -s http://$host/ >/dev/null; then
    echo "INFO: fetching http://$host/ worked" >&2
else
    rc=$?
    echo "ERROR: fetching http://$host/ failed (curl exit code $rc)" >&2
    exit $rc
fi
```

There are still failure scenarios where no specific HTTP result code will be returned, so I didn't want to put that in. If you need it, it's not hard to get `curl` to report it when it's available.

Bottom line, you need to understand what you're testing, and what a complete HTTP transaction looks like on the network level if that's what you're trying to test.

Notice also that diagnostic output goes to standard error (the `>&2` redirect).

A proper network test script is a drudge to write in shell script because there are so many things which could go wrong. Is there at least one physical network device? Is the cable plugged? Is there a route to the network? Can we resolve the remote host's name? Can we connect to it on a given port? (Your current script tests this.) Does whatever receives that connection speak the expected protocol? Does it handle a trivial request? Does it handle a specific nontrivial request? Is it handled correctly - are the results what we expected, both server-side and in the response the client received? (For example, if there is a database in the back end keeping state, is its state now different, in *only* the one aspect we are testing?)

A common annoyance is testing `GET /static-page` and not catching that the thing you *really* want to work is returning a 500 server error, but `POST /dynamic-content` with a test payload was too hard or tedious to automate so you never did.

Comment: If you really want to test `ssh`, similar points apply, though then the port number and the expected result codes would be different, and of course you'd use a proper `ssh` client instead of `curl` (though it has support for a number of protocols other than HTTP). I'm guessing your `echo` message are simply misleading, though, and that there isn't really any SSH here.

Comment: To get the status code from `curl`, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220301/how-to-evaluate-http-response-codes-from-bash-shell-script